# Table rowspan missing td textcontent after page break

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, html-table, puppeteer

im trying to print a table with react and puppeteer and it works awesome but im facing a problem when the page breaks in rowspan, the first td in my table contains some data that i need to show in the next page breaks also but the content of the first td is nothing after the page breaks, the table looks good for printing but i really need the td textcontent in every pagebreak.

As you can see in the first page the first td contains "1".
[image: First PDF page]

but, in next page texcontent is not showing for the first td.
[image]

is there any way to make it possible?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
var body = []
for (var i = 0; i < bodyData.length; i++) {
    var row = []
    for (var key in bodyData[i]) {
      row.push(bodyData[i][key])
    }
    if(i % 2 === 0){
        
        row.unshift({
            rowSpan: 2,
            content: i / 2 + 1,
            styles: { valign: 'middle', halign: 'center' },
          })
    }
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        row.unshift({
            colSpan: 11,
            //rowSpan: 2,
            content: "ColName:     " + bodyData[i].data,
            styles: { valign: 'middle', halign: 'left' },
        })
    }
   
    body.push(row)
}

bodyData = body;
```